# VS 2013 application does not running on VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, windows-xp

I have make an application on visual studio 2013 and I want to run this application on visual studio 2010 and dotNet framework 4.0 on my windows xp system but when I run my application I am getting an error below:

```
To run this application, you first must install one of the following versions of .Net Framework; .Net Framework, Version=v4.5
```

And also `.Net Framework, Version=v4.5` does not support on `windows xp`

Kindly suggest me what should I do, waiting for your reply.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your project properties, go to the dropdown "framwork" and select version 4.